# Stacked bar chart not showing and no errors in console log either

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wanted to plot this stacked bar chart with the filtering option but it's not showing up and I don't know where is the problem. I get no error in the console. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gty1996/u469hp1d/) is the full code.

And below you can find the javascript part which I don't know why isn't visualizing the barchart:

```
var csv = [
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "AL",
    "Under 5 Years": 552,
    "5 to 13 Years": 259,
    "14 to 17 Years": 310
  },
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "AK",
    "Under 5 Years": 856,
    "5 to 13 Years": 421,
    "14 to 17 Years": 520
  }
]


function chart(csv) {

    var keys = csv.columns.slice(2);

    var year   = [...new Set(csv.map(d => d.Year))]
    var states = [...new Set(csv.map(d => d.State))]

    var options = d3.select("#year").selectAll("option")
        .data(year)
    .enter().append("option")
        .text(d => d)

    var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
        margin = {top: 35, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 0},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
        .padding(0.1)

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

    var xAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
        .attr("class", "x-axis")

    var yAxis = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
        .attr("class", "y-axis")

    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .range(["steelblue", "darkorange", "lightblue"])
        .domain(keys);

    update(d3.select("#year").property("value"), 0)

    function update(input, speed) {

        var data = csv.filter(f => f.Year == input)

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.total = d3.sum(keys, k => +d[k])
            return d
        })

        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d3.sum(keys, k => +d[k]))]).nice();

        svg.selectAll(".y-axis").transition().duration(speed)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))

        data.sort(d3.select("#sort").property("checked")
            ? (a, b) => b.total - a.total
            : (a, b) => states.indexOf(a.State) - states.indexOf(b.State))

        x.domain(data.map(d => d.State));

        svg.selectAll(".x-axis").transition().duration(speed)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

        var group = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
            .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data), d => d.key)

        group.exit().remove()

        group.enter().append("g")
            .classed("layer", true)
            .attr("fill", d => z(d.key));

        var bars = svg.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
            .data(d => d, e => e.data.State);

        bars.exit().remove()

        bars.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .merge(bars)
        .transition().duration(speed)
            .attr("x", d => x(d.data.State))
            .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
            .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))

        var text = svg.selectAll(".text")
            .data(data, d => d.State);

        text.exit().remove()

        text.enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .merge(text)
        .transition().duration(speed)
            .attr("x", d => x(d.State) + x.bandwidth() / 2)
            .attr("y", d => y(d.total) - 5)
            .text(d => d.total)
    }

    var select = d3.select("#year")
        .on("change", function() {
            update(this.value, 750)
        })

    var checkbox = d3.select("#sort")
        .on("click", function() {
            update(select.property("value"), 750)
        })
}

chart(csv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by *"I get no error in the console"*? The error is clearly stated:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'csv.columns.slice')

What's happening is that you're using a property named `columns`, but there is no such property in `csv`, which is just a JavaScript array. That `columns` property is created by methods such as `d3.csv` and `d3.csvParse` (in your version, `d3.csv.parse`), when you load an external CSV file.

That being said, just do:

```
var keys = Object.keys(csv[0]).slice(2);
```

That's a easy alternative to the `columns` property created by these aforementioned D3 methods. This is what it does: `Object.keys`, as the name implies, ket's the keys of a given object. As all objects in your array have the same keys, we just need the first one, hence `csv[0]`. Then, using splice, we remove the first two keys, which are `Year` and `State`:

```js
var csv = [{
  "Year": 2017,
  "State": "AL",
  "Under 5 Years": 552,
  "5 to 13 Years": 259,
  "14 to 17 Years": 310
}];
console.log(Object.keys(csv[0]).slice(2));
```

As you can see, the important information is the index of the elements you want to remove.

Here is your code with that change only:

```js
var csv = [
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "AL",
    "Under 5 Years": 552,
    "5 to 13 Years": 259,
    "14 to 17 Years": 310
  },
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "AK",
    "Under 5 Years": 856,
    "5 to 13 Years": 421,
    "14 to 17 Years": 520
  },
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "AZ",
    "Under 5 Years": 828,
    "5 to 13 Years": 362,
    "14 to 17 Years": 515
  },
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "AR",
    "Under 5 Years": 343,
    "5 to 13 Years": 157,
    "14 to 17 Years": 202
  },
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "CA",
    "Under 5 Years": 449,
    "5 to 13 Years": 215,
    "14 to 17 Years": 270
  },
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "CO",
    "Under 5 Years": 587,
    "5 to 13 Years": 261,
    "14 to 17 Years": 358
  },
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "CT",
    "Under 5 Years": 403,
    "5 to 13 Years": 196,
    "14 to 17 Years": 211
  },
  {
    "Year": 2017,
    "State": "DE",
    "Under 5 Years": 794,
    "5 to 13 Years": 474,
    "14 to 17 Years": 593
  },
  {
    "Year": 2018,
    "State": "AL",
    "Under 5 Years": 310,
    "5 to 13 Years": 552,
    "14 to 17 Years": 259
  },
  {
    "Year": 2018,
    "State": "AK",
    "Under 5 Years": 520,
    "5 to 13 Years": 556,
    "14 to 17 Years": 421
  },
  {
    "Year": 2018,
    "State": "AZ",
    "Under 5 Years": 515,
    "5 to 13 Years": 828,
    "14 to 17 Years": 362
  },
  {
    "Year": 2018,
    "State": "AR",
    "Under 5 Years": 202,
    "5 to 13 Years": 343,
    "14 to 17 Years": 157
  },
  {
    "Year": 2018,
    "State": "CA",
    "Under 5 Years": 270,
    "5 to 13 Years": 449,
    "14 to 17 Years": 215
  },
  {
    "Year": 2018,
    "State": "CO",
    "Under 5 Years": 358,
    "5 to 13 Years": 587,
    "14 to 17 Years": 261
  },
  {
    "Year": 2018,
    "State": "CT",
    "Under 5 Years": 211,
    "5 to 13 Years": 403,
    "14 to 17 Years": 196
  },
  {
    "Year": 2018,
    "State": "DE",
    "Under 5 Years": 593,
    "5 to 13 Years": 994,
    "14 to 17 Years": 474
  }
]


function chart(csv) {

 var keys = Object.keys(csv[0]).slice(2);

 var year   = [...new Set(csv.map(d => d.Year))]
 var states = [...new Set(csv.map(d => d.State))]

 var options = d3.select("#year").selectAll("option")
  .data(year)
 .enter().append("option")
  .text(d => d)

 var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
  margin = {top: 35, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 0},
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .padding(0.1)

 var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

 var xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .attr("class", "x-axis")

 var yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .attr("class", "y-axis")

 var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["steelblue", "darkorange", "lightblue"])
  .domain(keys);

 update(d3.select("#year").property("value"), 0)

 function update(input, speed) {

  var data = csv.filter(f => f.Year == input)

  data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.total = d3.sum(keys, k => +d[k])
   return d
  })

  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d3.sum(keys, k => +d[k]))]).nice();

  svg.selectAll(".y-axis").transition().duration(speed)
   .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))

  data.sort(d3.select("#sort").property("checked")
   ? (a, b) => b.total - a.total
   : (a, b) => states.indexOf(a.State) - states.indexOf(b.State))

  x.domain(data.map(d => d.State));

  svg.selectAll(".x-axis").transition().duration(speed)
   .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

  var group = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
   .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data), d => d.key)

  group.exit().remove()

  group.enter().append("g")
   .classed("layer", true)
   .attr("fill", d => z(d.key));

  var bars = svg.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
   .data(d => d, e => e.data.State);

  bars.exit().remove()

  bars.enter().append("rect")
   .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
   .merge(bars)
  .transition().duration(speed)
   .attr("x", d => x(d.data.State))
   .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
   .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))

  var text = svg.selectAll(".text")
   .data(data, d => d.State);

  text.exit().remove()

  text.enter().append("text")
   .attr("class", "text")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .merge(text)
  .transition().duration(speed)
   .attr("x", d => x(d.State) + x.bandwidth() / 2)
   .attr("y", d => y(d.total) - 5)
   .text(d => d.total)
 }

 var select = d3.select("#year")
  .on("change", function() {
   update(this.value, 750)
  })

 var checkbox = d3.select("#sort")
  .on("click", function() {
   update(select.property("value"), 750)
  })
}

chart(csv);
```

```css
.axis .domain {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset ="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<style>
 
body {
 margin: auto;
 width: 650px;
 font: 12px arial;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<svg id="chart" width="650" height="400"></svg>

Select year: 
<select id="year"></select>

<input type="checkbox" id="sort"> 
Toggle sort 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works. As always helpful! Please, can you explain what does that line do. And how do I access the tree columns "Under 5 Years": 856, "5 to 13 Years": 421, "14 to 17 Years": 520 if I want to change them with different names from another dataset?